# Python regular expression substitute whitespace for hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I get a lob object that may have one or many dates.  thinking of the dates as a table if the first date is empty I get a chr(20).  ex 3rd element of array has a date the first two empty would look similar to " "," ","01/01/01 01:01:01".  I would like to change the " " in the date time string to something different ("-") so I can easily differentiate between just an empty element and an actual date time value with a space in the middle.  Brand new to python and regular expressions would not be considered my strong suit.

```
>>> x = '01/01/12 17:11:11'
>>> y = re.sub( r"\d{2} \d{2}", r"\d{2}-\d{2}",x)
>>> print (x,y)
01/01/12 17:11:11 01/01/\d{2}-\d{2}:11:11
```

Answer (score 3):

Use lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```
>>> import re
... x = '01/01/12 17:11:11 random junk 01/08/10 12:01:33'
... y = re.sub(r'(?<=\d{2}) (?=\d{2})', '-', x)
... y
103: '01/01/12-17:11:11 random junk 01/08/10-12:01:33'
```

Comment: Sure, just trump my regex solution by adding lookahead and lookbehinds ... I'll upvote anyway (1 more for moderator tools -- although they really aren't that exciting :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need regex?  What about `'-'.join(x.split())`?

Otherwise, you'll probably need to use groups:

```
y = re.sub( r"(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})", r"\1-\2",x)
```

Comment: He said the object (text?) may have many dates.  I think that there may be other spaces he doesn't want to replace, hence the regular expressions.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- Yeah, that's what I gathered as well, which is why I added a regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use:

```
x = x.replace(' ', '-')
```

Comment: It would also clobber the spaces that are place holders indicating not date was entered yet.  Space can mean 2 thing , a harmless format to make a date time string easier to read or it could indicate no date was entered yet.  If I clobber all the whitespace I wont know what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are overkill here.  Just use the string.replace() function:

```
>>> a='01/01/12 17:11:11'
>>> a.replace(' ','-')
'01/01/12-17:11:11'
```